# Martin Braun's Differential Equations and Their Applications or Arnold's Ordinary Differential Equations plus Evans' Partial Differential Equations?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, reference-request, book-recommendation

My objective is to study Ordinary and Partial Differential Equations in a theoretical way. 
I have 2 options on buying differential equations books in mind. These options are: (1) Differential Equations and Their Applications by Martin Braun and (2) Ordinary Differential Equations by V. I. Arnold plus Partial Differential Equations by Lawrence C. Evans.
The first option is without doubt more affordable. However, the second may be more complete and more suitable for my purpose of theoretical study. 
What do you recommend?